# Which ORM in java to use in parallel processing?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I want to create a parallel processing application in java in which dirty data committed  to one server is visible to other server.

Which is a case of DB transaction is being shared between two server.

Comment: you need a distribute transaction？

Comment: that data are already visible in simple situations, when the second server reads data after the first server have finished its transaction. If you mean some more complex situation, please describe it.

Comment: @TongChen How can i Achive that